# Maraschino cherry - can I use an alternative?

Tags: cocktails, alcohol

Just recently I have got into cocktails.  But I am finding it hard to find the right cherries so offset my designs.  The Maraschino cherry is the classic but what else is there to make my cocktails just that bit 'extra special'?

[This is what wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maraschino_cherry) has to say about the Maraschino cherry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

+1 for the Fabbri Amarena suggestion.

Another alternative is brandy (or other spirit) soaked cherries, they are [relatively easy to make](http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2011/07/brandied-cocktail-cherries-variations-on-maraschino-cherries-recipe.html) which allows you to control what kind of spirits, how much sugar, what kind of cherries, etc.  If you not willing/able to make them, they are also available from retailers, eg [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00P1P25PW)

Comment: Great idea making my own.

Answer (score 4):

There is the [Amarena cherry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amarena_cherry) was developed by Gennaro Fabbri and is a particular bitter cherry. Fabbri mixes them with a sort of jam and makes syrups with them.

The sensation is like the maraschino cherry, but more soft, enveloping and a bit less of sugar in it...

I found it perfect in all iced tea cocktail, to give them a twist, also good with pretty everything involving bayleys or similar creamy alcoholic
[reference here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amarena_cherry).

[This](http://www.mtnero.com/amarena-cherries/) may be of interest too.